# Autocomplete search box

Tags: php, search, autocomplete

I am making custom autocomplete search box. When my customer starts typing the first letter of a product name, I need to show all products which have that letter in their name. Same logic applies as he continues to type the whole product name. ( I hope my goal is clear)

I added the search box in my page like this:

```
<form class="search">
        <input id="products" name="products" type="text" />

    </form>
```

I included scripts in my header.php like this:

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netsh.pp.ua/upwork-demo/1/js/typeahead.js"></script>
```

I added script into my footer.php like this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input.products').typeahead({
                name: 'products',
                remote: 'products.php?query=%QUERY'

            });

        })
    </script>
```

I made mysql.php file in which I make connection to my mysql database and select query like this:

```
<?php

//CREDENTIALS FOR DB
define ('DBSERVER', 'here I put server name');
define ('DBUSER', 'here I put user name');
define ('DBPASS','here I put password');
define ('DBNAME','here I put database name');

//LET'S INITIATE CONNECT TO DB
$connection = mysqli_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS) or die("Can't connect to server. Please check credentials and try again");
$result = mysqli_select_db(DBNAME) or die("Can't select database. Please check DB name and try again");

//CREATE QUERY TO DB AND PUT RECEIVED DATA INTO ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $sql = mysqli_query ("SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%{$query}%' AND post_type LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $array[] = array (
            'label' => $row['post_title'].', '.$row['post_type'],
            'value' => $row['post_title'],
        );
    }
    //RETURN JSON ARRAY
    echo json_encode ($array);
}

?>
```

I put mysql.php to root folder. But when I start typing into search box, it doesn't act as autocomplete at all.

Comment: Hi Nancy, fantastic explanation of what you have tried and how you have gone about it, hope you get many +++ for making the effort.
I dont want to turn you away, but think, by me giving you this url to look at you will learn more yourself by it, than trying to get someone to do it for you.

Take a look at how the autocomplete is done here, especially the database connect. If you still fail after rading, by all means come back https://davidnash.com.au/create-an-auto-complete-field-in-wordpress/

Comment: "what to do" is not a real question as the answer is simply "debug your code". It is kind of obvious at least one problem in your code but I am going to be a little paternalist and say that it is probably will be more useful for you to learn how to debug ajax by yourself using browser tools, than getting an answer for this specific question. Side note, never do such things as your `mysql.php` in wordpress, this will likely end bad (but probably not the cause for your current problem)\

Comment: @MarkKaplun - thank you for the reply. As this is the first time ever I had to make this happen, I did do  my best with my current knowledge to make it work and I am failing. That's why  I asked question here, it wasn't just a lazy try in getting the job done for me. People do learn new things here too, I guess. Good point about mysql.php. Since the error is not obvious to me, I will try and debug it myself. Thanx again, anyway.

Comment: @Malisa - thank you for the link, i will look it up in order to get this resolved.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Is it Sooooo difficult for you to be nice sometimes? How are people EVER supposed to learn if you constantly put them down?
Dont get me wrong, 95% of the time your right with your comments about how questions are formed on here, but Jeeeez, Nancy has clearly made an effort and is looking for guidance. Oh and this comment is not that its wrong to state, but you could TRY to word in a different way.

Comment: @Malisa, many people believe that it is more important to teach people how to fish than to supply them fish

Comment: @MarkKaplun I agree entirely, 100%,  but just think about that.. How will a comment you made like that teach them anything? Anyway, this is not a forum, I was just making a comment to you about taking into consideration sometimes, peoples efforts.

Comment: that is cool. Maybe I should have said "learn how to debug ajax" and leave him with that, but I do tend to get overly verbose from time to time (about every 5 minutes ;) ) @Malisa

Comment: I still haven't been able to resolve this, i guess this will stay unresolved, since i do not know how to do this myself and I do not see what am I doing wrong. Came here for help, thanx to @Malisa I followed the link, but I just can't get this to work. I know, I should learn how to do this, but I am lost.

Comment: Hi Nancy, suggest, you edit your question above and now say what you have done to try to get this to work, add the code you have placed AND into which file (The File Name) e.g. header.php, functions.php.
Say what Exact problems your having now and what error messages(if any) your receiving

Comment: Hi Malisa,
I edited my code above to fit my current issue. I realised I used depreciated mysql instead of mysqli, so I updated the code. Also, I added id and name to my text box.But i still can't get it to work.

Comment: "Puzzled" @Nancy, Why are you not following exactly how it is in the link, why are you not using the WordPress way of adding JS files and database queries, as shown in the link I gave you?
You are on a WordPress Site?

Comment: Hi Malisa - Yes, on wordpress. I did follow the exact tutorial, but it doesn't work on my side. No mistakes in chrome console, ajax  checked, js loading checked and still no go. Whatever I do, i can't make it work. Thanx for all your help, though.